# Problem when booting from USB

Tags: boot, usb

Hi I am trying to install Ubuntu for the first time. After making the USB and booting I get this error: `0.221374 iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device= 00:00.0 pasid=0x00000 address=0xfffffffdf8000000 flags=0x0a00]`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? How as the USB made, what program was used? Did you verify the ISO before making the USB? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Were you following th offical guide to install Ubuntu? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I have tried 22.04 and 20.04. I have tried using Etcher, USB creator tool, etchdroid and Rufus. Yes, I have verified the ISO. I have also tried multiple USB drives and SD cards. Also tried installing Kali Linux and get the same error.

Comment: Since you get the same problem with Kali, the problem is unrelated to Ubuntu. It is somewhere else.

Comment: What brand/model system? Many AMD systems need iommu settings in UEFI changed  and/or iommu=soft as boot parameter in grub.

Comment: MSI b350 gaming plus, RX 580, Ryzen 1500x.